# How can I set scroll bar properties dynamically?

Tags: android, android-scrollbar

How can I set the property android:Scrollbars="none" dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

If you are using `HorizontalScrollView` then

```
horizontalScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```